# Получение значений динамически созданных input-ов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код, в котором `<input>` добавляются с помощью jQuery, но почему-то передается значение только первого созданного `<input>`-a.

```js
jQuery('form').on('click', '#serviceAdd a.pluss', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var plus = '<label><span> название услуги</span><input type="text" value="" name="servicesCode[]" class="servicesCode"></label><label><span> рекомендации данные в акте</span><input type="text" value="" name="servicesItself[]" class="servicesItself" /></label>'
    $('#serviceAdd').append(plus);
});
$('#addServices').click(function() {
    var sC=" ";
    $(".servicesCode").each(function() {
        sC += $(".servicesCode").val() + " ;%";
        alert($(".servicesCode").val());
    });
    alert(sC);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <section id="serviceAdd">
        <label>
            <span> название услуги</span>
            <input type="text" value="" name="servicesCode[]" class="servicesCode">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span> рекомендации данные в акте</span>
            <input type="text" value=""  name="servicesItself[]" class="servicesItself" />
        </label>
        <a href="#" class="pluss">+</a>
    </section>
    <a href="#" class="submit" id="addServices">Внести</a>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Если добавляю `<input>` и ввожу в первую пару `1`,`11`, а во вторую - `2`,`22`, то получаю ответы `alert`: первое окно - `1`, второе окно - `1`, третье - `1%;1%;`.

В чём проблема?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский извиняюсь эта часть кода сейчас поправлю

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  все поправил

Comment: @Regent Так я и спрашиваю в чем ошибка

Comment: @Regent  исправил :)  говорюже код не весь .

Comment: @Regent да в родном есть поставил здесь.

Comment: @Sergalas неактуальные теперь комментарии можно удалить, а решение проблемы я предоставил в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".servicesCode").val()` возвращает значение первого элемента, имеющего класс `servicesCode`. Для того чтобы получить значения всех элементов по очереди, можно использовать `$(this).val()` внутри `.each()`:

```js
$('form').on('click', '#serviceAdd a.pluss', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var plus = '<label><span> название услуги</span><input type="text" value="" name="servicesCode[]" class="servicesCode"></label><label><span> рекомендации данные в акте</span><input type="text" value="" name="servicesItself[]" class="servicesItself" /></label>';
    $('#serviceAdd').append(plus);
});
$('#addServices').click(function() {
    var sC = "";
    $(".servicesCode").each(function() {
        sC += $(this).val() + " ;%";
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    alert(sC);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <section id="serviceAdd">
        <label>
            <span> название услуги</span>
            <input type="text" value="" name="servicesCode[]" class="servicesCode">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span> рекомендации данные в акте</span>
            <input type="text" value=""  name="servicesItself[]" class="servicesItself" />
        </label>
        <a href="#" class="pluss">+</a>
    </section>
    <a href="#" class="submit" id="addServices">Внести</a>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```